# C: Pointer to pointer issue when I try to group a lot of things in it

Tags: c, list, pointers

I have a function that adds one item to a list that I created. If it's the first time and the list points to `NULL`, it allocates the list and completes it, returning the address. If it's not the first time, it adds another item and again returns the first item (by now I could disregard this return). The list and the function WORKS fine, here is the prototype:

```
typedef struct structTAppConsoleList {
    char *text;
    void (*cbFunction)(int);
    int number; // This is the item number
    struct structTAppConsoleList *previous;
    struct structTAppConsoleList *next;
} TList;

TList *AppConsoleListAddItem(TList *p_list, const char *p_string, void (*p_funcPtr)(int));
```

So, somewhere in my code I have to create a lot of them and I'm trying to make it as the code below shows. Thing is, I can't make it work... I want to create something to group the lists I want to create and then use it in the function. The code below is an idea of what I'm trying to do. Consider only the part where I try to allocate the 3 lists, the rest is not important for this example.

```
TList *list1;
TList *list2;
TList *list3;

int main(void)
{
    int i,j;
    TList **groupMyLists;
    TList *temp;

    groupMyLists=malloc(sizeof(TList)*3);

    *groupMyLists    =(TList*)&list1;
    *(groupMyLists+1)=(TList*)&list2;
    *(groupMyLists+2)=(TList*)&list3;

    for(j=0;j<3;j++) {
        temp=NULL;
        for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
            temp=AppConsoleListAddItem(temp,"some text",someFunc);
        }
        **groupMyLists=temp; // my make won't let me do this
        groupMyLists++;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that this would do it, but I can't compile it.

In my head, `(*groupMyLists)` would be the same as `(&list1)`, `(&list2)`, `(&list3)`, the same way that `(**groupMyLists)` would be the same as `(list1)`, `(list2)` and `(list3)`. So why I can't do `(**groupMyLists=temp)`? Anyone?

I hope I made myself clear!! I's not easy to explain this madness I'm trying to do...

Comment: This `TList ** groupMyLists=malloc(sizeof(TList)*3);` does not look good. You only need room for pointers to `TList`, not for the `TList`s themself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the above two answers about the incorrect indirection of `**groupMyLists` you probably also want to assign the `list1,list2,list3` pointers correct pointer values instead of writing garbage values into the allocated memory in `groupMyLists` i.e.

```
TList * groupMyList = malloc(sizeof(TList)*3);

list1 = &groupMyList[0];
list2 = &groupMyList[1];
list3 = &groupMyList[2];
```

but, this does not really match the rest of your code as it seems that `AppConsoleAddListItem` allocates the `temp` list so in that case your `malloc` would be incorrect as it should allocate the space for the pointers instead of space for the lists as in:

```
TList ** groupMyList = (TList **)malloc(sizeof(TList *)*3);
TList *  temp;

if (!groupMyList) {
   /* Print allocation error warning or handle in some proper fashion */
   exit(1);
}

for(j=0;j<3;j++) {
    temp=NULL;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
        temp=AppConsoleListAddItem(temp,"some text",someFunc);
    }
    groupMyLists[j]=temp; // Here you now assign the pointer in temp to the memory for                           // pointers that you allocated above
}

list1 = groupMyList[0]; // Here we need to assign the list1,2,3 after the AppConsole calls
list2 = groupMyList[1]; // as these calls will changes the pointer addresses written into
list3 = groupMyList[2]; // groupMyList
```

Although I can not be sure exactly what you are trying to do there are several inconsistencies of pointers and indirections in your original code and the above two examples can hopefully be of some guidance

Comment: I would suggest to improve the above code by checking if malloc was successful and also the compiler will issue a warning since the pointer returned by malloc is not casted before assignment.

Comment: @lfthikhan I agree, but the focus here was to just show the most obvious inconsistencies - not necessarily rewriting to optimal code. Nevertheless I will update the code. Thanks

Comment: @fnokke Thanks, this code solved my problem! I was looking to the problem from the wrong perspective, it's way simpler to point my lists AFTER they are already allocated.!

Answer (score 1):

Change this line, you are using the wrong indirection.

```
*groupMyLists=temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do the job:

```
**groupMyLists = *temp;
```

of copying one struct referenced by `temp` to another struct referenced by `*groupMyLists`.

But only if `*groupMyLists` would reference any valid memory, which is does not do - at least not from the source you posted.